# How can we add extra class with existing YOLOV5 model?

Tags: yolov5

I need to add an extra one class with the existing 80 class of YOLOV5. I am aware of custom training , but after that, it will lose the pretrained 80 classes information. My requirement is the existing 80 classes + 1 custom class

Answer (score 2):

Check the answer here: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1071

> you can label your new classes starting from 80 and then simply append
> your new data to coco in your data.yaml. See GlobalWheat2020.yaml for
> an example of training on multiple datasets.